# Why is <a href="myurl" type="submit" class="btn">Pay here</a> clearing the users form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this button on my webpage

`<a href="myurl" type="submit" class="btn"></a>`

For many users it just sends the user to the payment page (defined later, when jquery adds the URL via

`$("#id").attr("href",url)`

End users complain, that when clicking the link, the get returned to the form which is emptied ??

What can cause this?

Comment: are you actually going to a different page?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Is this a form? Because isn't it that a form needs input type button not a href?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how a form works. Instead of creating a link for a button and changing the hyperlink refernce attribute, you have to change the "action" property of the form itself.

Change your link to a submit button..

```
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

Give form an ID if it doesn't have one

```
<form id="myForm">
```

instead of changing the link on the button, change the form's action

```
$("#myForm").attr("action",url)
```

When the button is pressed the form will POST/GET to the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a form, a href is not used.

```
<input type="button" type="submit" class="btn">
```

The url is defined in the form tag, or anyway you like even in the javascript or jquery. But a href really redirects you anywhere and I think it does not submit a form.